# Do we need [softmax]?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, burninate-request

In a suggested edit review I noted a user suggesting a new tag [softmax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/softmax) I have rejected a couple of edits but I might be wrong doing so (I am new to that review queue). I think we don't need that tag.

- > Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is
  > applied? and is it unambiguous?

  It doesn't have a description of the tag.
- > Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

  It seems that it is about a specific function of neural networks
- > Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

  It could, but I am unsure, because then we could create a tag for each function used in neural networks.
- > Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

  I think the majority of this question has been tagged by the same user following the same common context neural network. (sometimes the post don't refer to softmax AFAIK)

Comment: What is it *meant* to refer to? Do you know? If not, then you are probably not the best person to be posting a burninate request. Looks to me like it is a specific type of mathematical function that may be relevant to computer science. Why do you think that this is a bad tag?  Lack of a description is trivially fixable, that's not a reason to burninate. Also, your assumption about a new user creating the tag is wrong—there are a number of questions with this tag, and they've had it for longer than a few days.

Answer (score 10):

The [softmax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function) is a function, just like [cos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cos) and [sin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sin).

I agree that it should include a description, but it is *not* unambiguous.

I went through many of questions that are tagged with it, most of them are on-topic and the tag actually describes the content, and it means the same in all common contexts. I don't think it should be burninated.

Comment: In fact, I was just using this term to search for logic behind the use of this last week, and found a great answer. At the very least, it's a good search term.